# How to represent Log-Normal Distribution

Tags: r, excel, statistics, probability, distribution

I am having trouble getting the following distribution represented in the picture below to give me correct values in excel. Can anyone give me any assistance?

Log Normal Distribution

[image]

Here is the formula I am using in excel.

```
=LOGNORM.INV(RAND(),2000,800)
```

A solution in R or excel would be nice.

Comment: Are you sure about those parameters? A log-normal distribution with a mean of 2000 and a standard deviation of 800 does not have that shape (Please see https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?x=0&y=0&i=plot+log-normal+mu%3D2000,+Sig%3D800 for a plot)

Comment: Im not sure about the parameters, Im guessing the parameters need to be transformed in order to get the correct distribution. However I do not know how to go about the transformation.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your previous statement please? Parameters are fixed values and they can not be transformed.

Comment: Here's how it looks in R: plot(dlnorm(0.0001*(1:10000), meanlog=2000, sdlog=800))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out. You have to use the conversion formulas (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution under Notation):

```
mean <- 2000
sd <- 800
meanlog <- log(mean/sqrt(1+sd^2/mean^2))
sdlog <- sqrt(log(1+sd^2/mean^2))
plot(density(rlnorm(100000, meanlog=meanlog, sdlog=sdlog)), xlim=c(0,5000))
```

[image]